# Algorithm Clarification--"Nested List Weight Sum"

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Working on the following problem from Leetcode:

> Given a nested list of integers, return the sum of all integers in the
>   list weighted by their depth.
>
> Each element is either an integer, or a list -- whose elements may
>   also be integers or other lists.
>
> Different from the previous question where weight is increasing from
>   root to leaf, now the weight is defined from bottom up. i.e., the leaf
>   level integers have weight 1, and the root level integers have the
>   largest weight.
>
> Example 1: Given the list [[1,1],2,[1,1]], return 8. (four 1's at
>   depth 1, one 2 at depth 2)
>
> Example 2: Given the list [1,[4,[6]]], return 17. (one 1 at depth 3,
>   one 4 at depth 2, and one 6 at depth 1; 1*3 + 4*2 + 6*1 = 17)

My strategy was to find the depth in one pass, and then each branch contributes (depth - branch_num) to the sum. So the top branch = depth, second branch is depth - 1, etc. Here's my code:

```
# This is the interface that allows for creating nested lists.
# You should not implement it, or speculate about its implementation
#
#class NestedInteger
#    def is_integer()
#        """
#        Return true if this NestedInteger holds a single integer, rather than a nested list.
#        @return {Boolean}
#        """
#
#    def get_integer()
#        """
#        Return the single integer that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a single integer
#        Return nil if this NestedInteger holds a nested list
#        @return {Integer}
#        """
#
#    def set_integer(value)
#        """
#        Set this NestedInteger to hold a single integer equal to value.
#        @return {Void}
#        """
#
#    def add(elem)
#        """
#        Set this NestedInteger to hold a nested list and adds a nested integer elem to it.
#        @return {Void}
#        """
#
#    def get_list()
#        """
#        Return the nested list that this NestedInteger holds, if it holds a nested list
#        Return nil if this NestedInteger holds a single integer
#        @return {NestedInteger[]}
#        """
#
# @param {NestedInteger[]} nested_list
# @return {Integer}
def depth_sum_inverse(nested_list)
    max_depth = max_depth(nested_list)
    depth_summation(nested_list, max_depth, 1)
end

def depth_summation(nested_list, max_depth, depth)
    sum = 0
    nested_list.each do |el|
        if el.get_integer.nil?
            sum += (max_depth - depth) + depth_summation(el.get_list, depth+1)
        else
            sum += el.get_integer*(max_depth - depth)
        end
    end
    sum
end 

def max_depth(nested_list)
    temp = 1 
    d = 1 
    nested_list.each do |el|
        temp = depth(el)
        if temp > d
            d = temp
        end
    end
    d
end


def depth(el)
    if el.is_integer
        return 1
    else 
        depth = 1 + depth(el.get_list)
    end

    depth    
end
```

The beginning commented out part is to help you understand the API of the "NestedInteger" class.

So here's where I'm struggling. I'm getting this error message:

> Line 69: in 'depth': undefined method 'is_integer' for
>    (NoMethodError).

The element is being recongized as an Array, when it should be an object of the NestedInteger class. Any idea why this is?

Comment: In `max_depth` you have a variable called `depth` that's probably shadowing the function. Doesn't explain the error exactly, but that's almost definitely an issue. Never name a variable the same thing as a function  if they're in the same scope. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Good point. Edited (updating code in problem now) but didn't help the error.

Comment: And I would expect a variable called `nested_list` to be a two-dimensional list. If that's the case, `el` is in fact a list, and it's what's being passed to `depth`, which would explain the error.

Comment: @Sunny - I ran the code and it produces: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'is_integer' for [1, 1]:Array` not `in 'depth': undefined method 'is_integer' for (NoMethodError).`,. You sure about the error?